# Ag-grid to show some editable columns vertically stacked without using row span

Tags: css, ag-grid, dash-ag-grid

I need to display a grid with dash-ag-grid in a way similar to row spanning in visuals but opposite in function. There's a need to have some editable columns to be stacked vertically as on the picture below

[image]

With ordinary html tables there's a way to change cell style from "display: table-cell" to "display: block" or to "display: inline-block" to obtain desired effect, it comes handy with responsive designs for smaller screens.

Is there a way to obtain similar result with ad-grid without resolving to multiplying rows in dataset and using row spanning?

Row spanning is the last resort as with it there will be trouble mapping values from various rows of not spanned editable columns to database. The imaginable solution with spanned rows will be to have some kind of master detail rendering with details having widgets or grids to edit values for editable columns of selected row. Implementing master-detail seems as an overhead, so some CSS or ad-grid params based solution is desirable.